# GWT enforcing Widgets horizontally and having scrollbar

Tags: css, gwt, flowpanel

I am having a FlowPanel with Float Left set in GWT inside a ScrollPanel. I want to enforce that instead of wrapping the new content to next line it gets added horizontally into FlowPanel and Scrollbar appears.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can do

```
Verticalpanel v= new verticalpanel;

v.add(flowpanel);//styles on flow panel

v.add(morecontent);

scrollpanel.setWidget(v);
```